# Proof for multiple linear orders using Erdős–Szekeres theorem

Tags: combinatorics

I need help with a combinatorics Exercise:
The exercise is as follows:

> "Let X be a Set with |X| = $(n^4+1)$ for an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\leq_1,\leq_2,\leq_3$ 3 linear orders on X. Proof that there exists a sequence of length $n+1$ that is monotonous for all 3 orders."

I understand that the Erdős–Szekeres theorem proves the existence of sequences of length $n^2+1$ for each order, and by using it twice it proves the existence of sequences of length $n+1$ for each combination of the three linear orders. However I don't quite understand how to derive a monotonous sequence for all 3 Orders from this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  By relabeling elements if necessary, without loss of generality, $X = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n^4+1 \}$ and $\leq_1$ is the usual order on $\Bbb N$.  Now use Erdős–Szekeres to see that there must be a monotonic subsequence of length $n^2+1$ for $\leq_2$, and that subsequence must have a smaller monotonic subseqence of length $n+1$ for $\leq_3$.